# Misaligned left and right y-axes in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I have a chart of profits&losses I made trading stocks in absolute ($) and relative (%) values. Today I made my first trade that brought me losses, and **adding negative values to the chart caused its y-axes to misalign**.

[image: chart]

I tried manipulating the min/max values, but to no avail. I googled people having similar problems, but not in Google Sheets.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: try changing the gridlines counts in the customize chart dialogue. But know that charting in google sheets is not the best.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @a-burge, it worked, but I know it is just a temporary solution, that might require fildding around with any new data. thanks anyways, my grief is no more as I know how to fix it.

Comment: @player0 [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iisM-pPyRznkOG7UupXf6ShVp6qFkjNJwDO8U3v0wHs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

The `Auto` gridline count can behave wrongly with particular datasets. When handling such datasets it will be necessary to tweak the major gridline count from the Chart Editor:

`Edit Chart>Customize>Gridlines` and adjust the major gridline count accordingly.